# Orbot stops for no reason on my Android 7.0 phone

Tags: orbot, android

Orbot starts and works fine alongside with Orfox and Twitter but it frequently stops (it does not crash, it just stops working): the persistent notification icon disappear and Orfox issues the typical "the proxy server is refusing connections" message. I have been using Orbot and Orfox since I had an android 4.0 device but I am experiencing this problem with my Android 7.0 phone. Is it a known issue or it's just me and my jinx?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed orbit and orfox from the guardian repo on fdroid. I have a OnePlus 3 on lineage is 14.1, Android 7.1.2. It is working just fine for me. What device and os are you using?